# Open previous tab when reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with my site. It has a page with two tabs. In the second tab, there is a pagination and I'm using bootstrap. The issue I'm having is when I click a different page on the pagination, it goes back to the 1st tab.

I have tried to fix it using hash links. When I do that, it flashes the 1st tab for milliseconds and then shows the 2nd tab which is not what I want. I want it to show the same tab even after clicking the pagination. Also, note that I'm using Ajax.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="resumes-tab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#shortlisted-resumes-list" aria-expanded="true">Shortlisted</a></li>
    <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#download-resumes-list" aria-expanded="false">Downloads</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="shortlisted-resumes-list" class="tab-pane fade active in">
        <div class="cs-resumes" data-adminurl="https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="download-resumes-list" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="cs-resumes" data-adminurl="https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php">
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i>Previous</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="active">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Next" onclick="cs_dashboard_tab_load('resumes', 'employer', 'https:\/\/example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', '83', '','2')"><span aria-hidden="true">Next <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my jQuery snippet

```js
<script>
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    var prefix = "";

    if (hash) {
        jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash.replace(prefix, "") + '"]').tab('show');
    }

    // Change hash for page-reload
    jQuery('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".cs-dash-resumes-tabs").offset().top }, "slow");
    });
</script>
```

Why does this happen? Because I'm using Ajax?

Comment: _“when I click a different page on the pagination, it goes back to the 1st tab”_ - you mean, right then when you click? Or after reloading the page next, as you question title seems to indicate?

Comment: Pagination is on the 2nd tab. When I click through pages in the pagination, the page reloads and open the 1st tab automatically. With the jQuery code, I have managed to switch to tab 2 however the 1st tab still shows for milliseconds and then quickly opens. 2nd tab.

Comment: _“When I click through pages in the pagination, the page reloads”_ - I thought you were using AJAX for that? _“however the 1st tab still shows for milliseconds and then quickly opens. 2nd tab.”_ - well yeah, that is to be expected. The browser starts rendering your HTML first, and in that, the first tab has the class `active`, so it shows initially. Your script “fixing” that happens only afterwards. Other than placing your script as closely after that block of HTML as possible (if you have jQuery loaded by than already?), there isn’t that much you can do about this.

Comment: Yes, I do use AJAX for that. Sorry, my bad. Data comes through AJAX without page being reloaded in fully. Yet it shows tab 1. Is there any way I can pass through the data via AJAX? Activating the second tab directly?

Comment: _“Yet it shows tab 1”_ - then your AJAX part is probably replacing more than just the content of the second tab, but larger parts of the HTML structure, including the HTML that makes up the first tab.